# Render map key in first row of h:dataTable only

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have been searching on how to display a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>` using c:forEach. I am attempting to print a list of words in alphabetical order and showing the key once in the same line than the first element in the ArrayList.

```
A Apple
  Arpa
  Adverb
```

---

```
B Background
  Ball
  Ballad
...
```

The signature of the map is:

```
private Map<String, ArrayList<String>> procedures;
```

I'm rendering it as below:

```
<c:forEach items="#{obj.procedures}" var="entry" varStatus="counter"> 
    <h:column><h:outputText value="&#160;#{entry.key}"/> </h:column>
    <h:dataTable value="#{entry.value}" var="foo">                                       
        <h:column><h:outputText value="&#160;&#160;" /></h:column>                    
        <h:column><h:outputText value="&#160;#{foo}" /></h:column>                    
    </h:dataTable>
    <p:separator></p:separator>
</c:forEach>
```

However, the result is slightly different because the first letter appears one line above of the first record instead of showing in the same line than the first record in the list of values.

Current result:

```
A 
  Apple
  Arpa
  Adverb
_________________
B 
  Background
  Ball
  Ballad
    ...
```

Cheers

Comment: You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render it **inside** the `<h:dataTable>`, not **outside**. Just move the `<h:column>` rendering the map key back into the `<h:dataTable>`.

```
<c:forEach items="#{obj.procedures}" var="entry">
    <h:dataTable value="#{entry.value}" var="foo">
        <h:column>#{entry.key}</h:column>
        <h:column>#{foo}</h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</c:forEach>
```

This will produce:

```
A  Apple
A  Arpa
A  Adverb

B  Background
B  Ball
B  Ballad
```

Then, in order to let it show up only in the first row, simply check if the table's current row index equals to 0. You can get it by consulting [`UIData#getRowIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowIndex--). You can from inside a `<h:column>` access the parent `<h:dataTable>`, which is an `UIData`, via the `#{component.namingContainer}` expression.

```
<c:forEach items="#{obj.procedures}" var="entry">
    <h:dataTable value="#{entry.value}" var="foo">
        <h:column><h:outputText value="#{entry.key}" rendered="#{component.namingContainer.rowIndex eq 0}" /></h:column>
        <h:column>#{foo}</h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</c:forEach>
```

```
A  Apple
   Arpa
   Adverb

B  Background
   Ball
   Ballad
```

By the way, use CSS `margin`, `padding` and `border` for whitespace and borders, not non-breaking spaces or separator components. It makes your markup unnecessarily bloated and maintenance-unfriendly.

Comment: Why this change is only showing the list of C words for every letter?And shown in horizontal instead of vertical?

Comment: Because it was using <c:forEach> instead of <ui:repeat>, I overlooked that important bit. See updated answer.